# SwiftUI macOS VideoPlayer View Only Crashes In Notarized (Distributed) App

Tags: swiftui, video-player, avkit

In brief, my macOS app written purely in SwiftUI uses VideoPlayer to present a locally stored video (not bundled).  The pertinent code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct CustomizedPlayerView: View {
    @State var player: AVPlayer?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let avPlayer = self.player {
                VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer).frame(minWidth: 320, minHeight: 320)
            }
            Text("Problematic VideoPlayer View")
        }
    }
}
```

When building for development in Xcode, there are no issues (no crashes, no issues playing).

However, opening the view in the notarized app, causes the entire app to crash with `Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)`.  This signals to me that the system is aborting my app because of an improper assignment of a nil value, but the player does seem to pass a non-nil value at the time of crash.

I figured out the issue after some debugging and researching.  I wanted to share what worked for me and hope it will save someone time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to add `AVKit.framework` manually to `Link Binary With Libraries` in the app target's `Build Phases` in Xcode.

[image: Link AVKit Framework with Libraries]

It turns out the SwiftUI AVKit's `VideoPlayer` view is nil in the archived app, presumably not linked or built with AVKit.

This blog post is the source: [Source](https://swiftui-lab.com/videoplayer-bug/). All credit to Javier at The SwiftUI Lab.  Surprisingly, the issue seems to be present since around June 2020.

Bug Report: FB8928032